# Why does modulus increases with strain rate?

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

This seems counterintuitive to me. My initial understanding is that higher strain rate means the material give in to more stretch per time with constant load. Should this means the material is more flexible?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The curves shows that plastic deformation for this material is obtained keeping the same stress (after an initial % of strain for all curves).

But in order to increase the speed of plastic deformation (the different strain rate between curves), it is necessary higher stresses.

The mechanisms of plastic deformation requires to move some internal defects called dislocations. They are present before the deformation begins, and increase during the process.

While dislocations are the reason why plastic deformation happens, its sharply increase make each of them interfere in the free movement of the others. That explains the *strain hardening*, the increase of stress in the first part of the process, just after the elastic range.

Thermal activated mechanisms can group or eliminate much of them, what allows further strain. But that needs time, so higher strain rates need more stress to get the same strain.

Comment: I dont think i am following. First question: does strain rate increases with the stress value? I thought its an inherent property thats unique to that material. But if it so, my second question, with regards to your last statement, should a material with a lower strain rate need an even larger stress to get the same strain?

Comment: @ Hans Keegan Phenca it is the opposite: strain rate is an independent variable. You can settle the testing device to force a given velocity. The stress is an outcome: the load cells of the device will record it. So, if you set a slow deformation rate, the device will need less effort, and record smaller stress.

Comment: got it. wow. thx a lot. I think I messed up the cause and effect order of all these variables mentioned.